# Order popular items with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have a list A of products where in which I can get the most popular products over time. I also have a list B of products. This list will change every day.

What I want to do is display all the products of list B and order it with the popular products of list A. For example:

List A will contain:

```
banana
apple
banana
orange
apple
banana
```

List B will contain:

```
potato
rice
banana
bread
orange
```

Now the output has to be:

```
banana
orange
potato
rice
bread
```

How do I do this with a single SQL command?
Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what your ordering criteria are. Can you please clarify? Also please show structure of the relevant tables so people can give advice on how to join if needed.

Comment: So the A list (table) will have multiple rows of "banana" (for example) - one for each "unit of popularity"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT B.Col1, CNT FROM LISTB B
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT Col1, COUNT(*) CNT 
     FROM LISTA A GROUP BY Col1) A1 ON b.col1 = A1.col1
    ORDER BY CNT DESC
```

Check this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34f5f/1